# Can I Use Android's Wifi P2P Api To Transfer SQLite Data Between Apps?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-wifi, data-transfer, wifip2p

I want to create an Android app where I can leverage the wifi api to transfer data between two app on separate devices. Essentially, I want to transfer data from SQLite database of the first app to be populated into the SQLite database of another app. If this is not possible, what are some available options I can look into? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do this there are different methods which you can apply to do this
like you can write a script to prepare a json object of your data and then send it to the other side and where a script can read this json data

or you can send specific data from your database using the standard wifi p2p methods you can do this using sockets also